# How do I prevent the Javascript InfoVis SpaceTree `ST.select()` method from collapsing nodes?

Tags: javascript, visualization, charts, infovis

I'm using the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit and in particular the [SpaceTree](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.html) visualisation.

I need to expand all of the tree and then show a path from a particular leaf node back to the root.

I've got the tree to expand just fine but it's the selection of a leaf node and highlighting the path back to the root that's causing me some problems.

I'm using the `ST.select(node, onComplete)` function to select the leaf node I'm interested in and indeed the path back to the root (lines and nodes) are highlighted.

To do this I implemented the `onBeforePlotNode` and `onBeforePlotLine` `ST.Controller` methods to allow me to highlight the nodes back to the root and their plotlines:

```
onBeforePlotNode: function(node){  
  //add some color to the nodes in the path between the  
  //root node and the selected node.  
  if (node.selected) {  
    node.data.$color = "#dddddd";  
  } else {  
    delete node.data.$color;  
  }  
},
onBeforePlotLine: function(adj){
  if (adj.nodeFrom.selected && adj.nodeTo.selected) {
    adj.data.$color = "#33CC33";
    adj.data.$lineWidth = 5;
  } else {
    delete adj.data.$color;
    delete adj.data.$lineWidth;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `ST.select()` to highlight the leaf node all child nodes beneath this level are collapsed/hidden.

To see this in action I've uploaded a couple of examples:

> [Full tree expansion - leaf not selected](http://zygonia.net/so/ex1.html)
>   [Leaf selected - path shown, but all children below node N2 missing](http://zygonia.net/so/ex2.html)

You may need to scroll down if your browser window is a bit small.

So my question is, how do I show nodes from a leaf node back to the root node in JavaScript InfoVis without collapsing level 3's children (level 1 being the root)?

If there was a way to find my leafe node and walk the tree back to the root (setting styles on the way) then I'd be happing doing that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK after digging through all that code, cluttering it with console.log() calls and breakpoints, I found it.

It has to do with the inital `onClick` call, the fact that the graph as an update loop that's running in the background and the fact that everything besides `onClick` seems to ignore the `busy` state of the graph.

**What happens**

1. `onClick` gets called and triggers a chain of events, part of them is asynchronous
2. `select` is being called which is more or less synchronous and does its work
3. `onClick` finally gets done and one of it's side effects is that it re-expands the graph
4. `select` has set `clickedNode` and now `onClick` uses the newly set value of it and screws up

**Solution**

We need to redesign `select` so it respects the busy state of the graph:

```
select: function(id, onComplete) {
    var that = this;
    if (this.busy) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            that.select(id, onComplete);

        }, 1);
        return;
    }
    // original select code follows here (remove the old var that = this; assignment)
```

That's all, we simply check for the busy state and delay select until it's `false`.
This should also be applied to all other function besides `onClick` that are called from the outside, the library designer here did a bad job of indicating what has side effects and what has not though.

Comment: much appreciated again, you're a star!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting "constrained: false" in ST's properties? That solved it for me.

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Spacetree-js.html